# Unexpected "double" namespace when using constructor function in submodule

Tags: javascript

I'm building my first real JS app (a tower defense game) and I've been struggling a little with my app structure. I've read about no littering the global namespace so I want to keep all my code in one single global variable while still being able to split my code in files (modules). I have managed to do this but I'm having doubts if I'm going the correct way with this.

The actual problem I'm having now is that when I create "entity" objects (through a constructor function which is actually a method of a submodule), the namespace is not app.entity.type_1 as I expected but app.entity.entity.type_1

```
/*
** file 1 (included first in html)
*/

var APP = (function (app) {
    entity = app.entity || {};
    entity.tracker = [];

    app.init = function () {
        entity.tracker.push(new app.entity.type_1(entity.tracker.length));
        entity.tracker.push(new app.entity.type_2(entity.tracker.length));
        console.log(entity.tracker[0]);
        console.log(entity.tracker[1]);
    };

    return app;

})(APP || {});

/*
** file 2 (included after file 1 in html)
*/

APP.entity = (function (entity) {

    entity.type_1 = function (id) {
        this.type = "type 1";
        this.id = id;
    };

    entity.type_2 = function (id) {
        this.type = "type 2";
        this.id = id;
    };

    return entity;

})(APP.entity || {});

APP.init();
```

Please check out the fiddle below.
http://jsfiddle.net/Percept/8stFC/13/

My question is, why does it repeat the "entity" namespace and how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're referring to what Chrome thinks the class name is, that's just a best guess on its part. Since JavaScript has no first-class concept of namespaces, all the context it's really got is that the function that created it was assigned to a variable that was at the time called `entity.type_1`, and that that was within an IIFE whose result was assigned to `APP.entity`. Chrome thought the most helpful thing to do would be to concatenate those. You're not doing anything wrong, it's just that Chrome made a bad guess. For the record, Firefox just says `[object Object]`.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer, been looking 4 hours for a reason why chrome did this (should have checked other browsers).

Is there any way to "overwrite" this?

Comment: I was just thinking about cloning the new returned entity object into a new object within my main APP IIFE, that way I should be able to control the namespace but it seems a little over the top just to get the naming right.